which model was chosed by automl in pycaret
Using pycaret,
top5 = s.compare_models(n_select=5)
ensembled_top5 = [ensemble_model(i, choose_better = True) for i in top5]
best_mae_model = automl(optimize = 'MAE')

the ensembled_top5[0] is better than top5[0], while I did not get the performace of automl and what is the final model choosen by automl? Thank you.
When print these models, I'm not sure which one is the best performance CatBoostRegressor model as automl gave different "at 0x78xxxxxxx" from  the top5[0] and ensembled_top5[0].
print(top5[0])
<catboost.core.CatBoostRegressor object at 0x78b4d08206d0>

print(ensembled_top5[0])
BaggingRegressor(estimator=<catboost.core.CatBoostRegressor object at 0x78b44425a790>,
             random_state=123)

print(best_mae_model)
BaggingRegressor(estimator=<catboost.core.CatBoostRegressor object at 0x78b4d08e29d0>,
             random_state=123)

